# Print PDF content with additional text?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I have a PDF file embedded in a HTML page.
In the page I have a title + content + print button.

I want that when someone clicks the button - he will get a print of the pdf + the title and content from the page.

I couldn't find anything like that in Google.

Can you help me with it please?

Answer (score 0):

Its not easy to set a page with PDF inclusions usually when nested PDF as embedment becomes blank.
[image]
So you need to fiddle with complex js re-renderings like this example. It would be much easier to use simple embedded images, as per both our combined codes.

[image]